# Automating Date range for Silverpop

Tags: xml, ibm-cloud-tools

Every week i have to manually put date range, is there any why that i can automate date range. suppose my date range be like
 'Yesterday' and '10DaysAgo'
I want that my below code will automatically consider system date and work accordingly.
I am using this code to pull data from silverpop. This code is provided by IBM Silverpop worksheet http://www.bbcknowledge.com/extensions/bbcww_newsletter_form_component/frontend/assets/style/7.4%20API%20Test%20Harness%20and%20Documentation/XML%20API%20Definition%20for%20Recipient%20and%20User%20Actions.pdf  (Page 90)

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"windows-1252\"?>
        <Envelope>\r\n
        <Body>\r\n
        <GetAggregateTrackingForOrg>\r\n
        <DATE_START>02/19/2017 00:00:00</DATE_START>\r\n
        <DATE_END>02/25/2017 23:59:59</DATE_END>\r\n
        </GetAggregateTrackingForOrg>\r\n
        </Body>\r\n
        </Envelope>"
```